# How to query 3 tables and check for date in SQL?

Tags: sql

[image]

The question is :

3. Sales people must be trained to make orders. For a sales person to receive credit for an order, the order_date must fall between a training start and end date for that sales person.

   Write a query that finds all orders where the sales person did not have an active training on the order date.

So far I have :

```
 SELECT * 
FROM Salesperson t1
INNER JOIN Orders t2 on Training t3 
WHERE Start_date = order_date ?
```

Since date is formatted in month/day/year, how can you just check for year, and also run 3 table queries?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Are those dates stored in varchjar or date data type columns?

Comment: If below answer answered your question please mark it as so.

Answer (score 1):

I think you asked two questions.

Regarding the first one:

My idea was to first find the orders that have taken place during a training (inner query below) and then (with that) find the orders that are not included in that list (those are the ones that have happened outside a training).

```
select ord.* from orders ord
left join ( -- now comes the query that gets all orders that have happened during a training
select unique ord.id as order_id from orders ord
left join training train on train.salesperson_id = ord.salesperson_id
where ord.order_date > train.start_date and ord.order_date < train.end_date
) with_training on ord.id = with_training.order_id
where with_training.order_id IS NULL
```

The direct approach of finding the orders that have not happened during a training seems to be a bit complicated (at least for me right now), because there can be more than one training for one salesperson.

Regarding your second question: The `year()` function in SQL should provide the year of the date and should help you make the necessary comparisons.